# How to change the default system font for Bengali in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS?

Tags: fonts, language-support, default, default-programs, ubuntu-font-family

I don't like the default Bengali font in Ubuntu which is possibly Lohit Bengali. Is it possible to change? Want to change it to kalpurush.ttf but how can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to change the default Bangla font in LibreOffice? File explorer (Nautilus)? Everywhere?

Comment: I want to change the bangla font in which the OS shows month, date etc